# using card view and recyclerView in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to use the new android component (cardView and recyclerView). but I work with eclipse and I try with a different way but it's not work for me.how should i do ?

```
Error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.cardviewexemple-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.cardviewexemple-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]].
```

Comment: do you add library project cardView and recyclerView

Comment: yes I add it. by adding jar file to libs and adding those to build path

Comment: where did you find this both .jar ?, here in android sdk/extras/ provide that both card and recycleview library project that import and add ad library project

Comment: I used this : http://happilycoded.com/blog/using-recyclerview-and-cardview-in-eclipse-adt/
to make jars.

and I try also with adding library project. for example I add cardview  libproject from here :\sdk\extras\android\support\v7